# How to fix the table of contents when I have defined a specific format for my sections?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, roman-numerals

So, I defined my sections to be roman and having the text "Article". I created a table of contents with hyperref, the links work and the sections themselves are just fine, but the table of contents are distorted:
[image]

I have only used the following commands, so everything should have been automatically created, have I missed anything specific here?

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Article \Roman{section}:}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
\tableofcontents
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package to provide more space for the numbers plus "Article".

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{...} % perhaps 6em?
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{...} % perhaps 10em?
```

Read the documentation (`texdoc tocloft`).